# div popup doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, php

Im trying to make a div popup when i press the image but when i press the image nothing happens. It works if i use the code outside of the loop so obv it has something to do with the loop, but what?

```
    <table>
        <?php 
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

           echo "<tr><td> <a href = 'javascript:void(0)' onclick = 'document.getElementById('a').style.display='block';document.getElementById('b').style.display='block''><img src='1.jpg' id='s_album' style='align:center;'></a> 

           }
        ?>
    </table> 
           <div id='a' class='white_content'>text <a href = 'javascript:void(0)' onclick = 'document.getElementById('a').style.display='none';document.getElementById('b').style.display='none'>close</a></div>
           <div id='b' class='black_overlay'></div></td></tr>";
```

Comment: You are adding multiple `div`-s with same `id`.

Comment: I really encourage you stop writing inline JavaScript like this, there are a [variety of reasons](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/) to do so. Anyway, I believe that Olavi Sau's answer is the correct solution for this specific problem.

Comment: <script></script> are even better than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onclick will be rendered falsely, to be more precise you have multiple single quotes, those will be rendered as is, thus your onclick script ends prematurely.

Just escape the double quotes  like this \"

```
document.getElementById(\"a\").style.display=\"block\";document.getElementById(\"b\").style.display=\"block\"'
```

Comment: absolutely. need to wait 5 mins to be able to do it